# Catia V5 Macro: Incomplete renaming function

Tags: vba, catia

I've been dealing with this a while and even had help but i can't work it out.
The following macro renames `PartName` or `InstanceName` depending on user and CADSelection.

Problem is it's not working in `PartName` alteration.
Can someone help me complete this macro? and ideally explain what i did incorrectly?

```
Sub CATMain()

  If CATIA.Documents.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "There are no CATIA documents open. Please open a CATIA document and try again.", ,msgboxtext
    Exit Sub
  End If

  If InStr(CATIA.ActiveDocument.Name, ".CATProduct") < 1 Then
    MsgBox "The active document is not a Product. Please open a CATIA Product and try again.", ,msgboxtext

    Exit Sub
  End If

  Dim oSelection As Selection
  Set oSelection = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection

  If oSelection.Count < 1 then
    MsgBox "Pick some components using cad selection."
  Else
    '****** Alter Instance Name *****'
    Dim msg
    msg = MsgBox ("Click ""Yes"" to change Instance Name, ""No"" to change Part Name or ""Cancel"" to exit", _
       vbYesNoCancel, "Renaming Tool")

    if vbYes = msg then
      '****** Inputbox for Instance name alteration *****
      Dim NewIName As String
      NewIName = InputBox("Please input the desired Instance Name. Example: E","Instance name alteration","E")
      '****** Inputbox for Instance number alteration *****
      Dim NewINumber As Integer
      NewINumber = InputBox("Please input the initial number for the 1st component. Example: 1","Instance numbering alteration","1")

      Dim oIBody
      Dim InstName As Body
      For oIBody = 1 to oSelection.Count
         Set InstName = oSelection.Item(oIBody).Value
         '****** Instance name alteration *****
         InstName.Parent.Parent.ReferenceProduct.Products.Item( _
                  InstName.Name).Name= NewIName + CStr(NewINumber)
         NewINumber=NewINumber+1
      Next
    elseif vbNo = msg then
      '****** Inputbox for Part name alteration *****
      Dim NewPName As String
      NewPName = InputBox("Please input the desired Part Name. Example: E","Part Name alteration","E")

      '****** Inputbox for Part number alteration *****
      Dim NewPNumber As Integer
      NewPNumber = InputBox("Please input the initial number for the 1st Component. Example: 1","Part numbering alteration","1")

      Dim oPBody
      Dim PartName As Body

      For oPBody = 1 to oSelection.Count
        Set PartName = oSelection.Item(oPBody).Value

        '****** Part name alteration *****
        PartName.ReferenceProduct.Name= NewPName + CStr(NewPNumber)
        NewPNumber=NewPNumber+1
      Next
    End If
  End If

  oSelection.Clear
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part "name" is really the Part Number and is changed using the "PartNumber" property.

So try changing

```
PartName.ReferenceProduct.Name= NewPName + CStr(NewPNumber)
```

to

```
PartName.ReferenceProduct.PartNumber= NewPName + CStr(NewPNumber)
```

This doesn't influence the document name unless you have not saved your part already.

What else :

1) Your variable naming is confusing. You call the Product "InstName" in one place and "PartName" in another. At first glance I thought those were strings. Using oProduct would be less confusing.

2) You seem real confident that the user has pre-selected the correct types. Since you are selecting in an assembly, instead of using Selection.Item(i).Value, you can use **Selection.item(i).LeafProduct** which will always be the instance product of whatever object is selected. Even if the user picks a surface, it will return the instance product which contains the selected surface.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion completely solved my problem. To clarify why my  code looks like that: 
1) The idea was to be able to edit either Instance Name or the Part Name of at least one CATPArt / CATProduct. The simplicity of the code was also requested.
2) The selection of CATPArts / CATProducts to be altered is done specifically in the spec tree.